# Como utilizar a biblioteca jsondiffpatch?

Tags: javascript, json, array

Estou tendo dúvidas de como manipular os dados com a biblioteca [jsondiffpatch](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch)

O *array* original:

```
[
  {"id":1004,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Alface","preco":1,"quantidade":1},
  {"id":1000,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Bacon","preco":2,"quantidade":1},
  {"id":1001,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Queijo Cheedar","preco":2,"quantidade":3}
]
```

O *array* modificado:

```
[
  {"id":1004,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Alface","preco":1,"quantidade":2},
  {"id":1001,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Queijo Cheedar","preco":2,"quantidade":1},
  {"id":1002,"idproduto":2,"forma":"Bacon","preco":2,"quantidade":1}
]
```

A resposta da biblioteca é:

```
[0: {
quantidade: [1,2]
},1: {
quantidade: [3,1]
},2{
  "id": 1002,
  "idproduto": 2,
  "forma": "Bacon",
  "preco": 2,
  "quantidade": 1
}]
```

Ele exibe a diferença certa. A minha dúvida é: Com base nessa diferença, como manipulo esse *array* para virar um novo??

Da seguinte forma:

```
[
  {"id":1004,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Alface","preco":1,"quantidade":1},
  {"id":1001,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Queijo Cheedar","preco":2,"quantidade":-2},
  {"id":1002,"idproduto":2,"forma":"Bacon","preco":2,"quantidade":1}
]
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54202/discussion-on-question-by-willian-como-utilizar-a-biblioteca-jsondiffpatch)

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a documentação da biblioteca é só usar a função `patch` que já vem com a biblioteca.

Ex.:

```
var original = [
    {"id":1004,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Alface","preco":1,"quantidade":1},
    {"id":1000,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Bacon","preco":2,"quantidade":1},
    {"id":1001,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Queijo Cheedar","preco":2,"quantidade":3}
];

var modificado = [
    {"id":1004,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Alface","preco":1,"quantidade":2},
    {"id":1001,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Queijo Cheedar","preco":2,"quantidade":1},
    {"id":1002,"idproduto":2,"forma":"Bacon","preco":2,"quantidade":1}
];

var diferenca = jsondiffpatch.diff(original, modificado);

// modifica o original
jsondiffpatch.patch(original, diferenca);

console.log(original);
```

Editei o Fiddle para que fizesse o patch da biblioteca.
[<kbd>Fiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/pvnxkjee/1/)

**EDIT**: Modifiquei o código e adicionei o Fiddle

Comment: Acho que não é esse resultado que ele quer, repare que na pergunta a saída desejada tem `-2` para o queijo (que é a diferença entre a quantidade original e a modificada).

Comment: `Com base nessa diferença, como manipulo esse array para virar um novo?`.
Eu entendi que ele queria juntar a diferença com o array antigo... Mas pra fazer isso que tu disse é só ele parsear o diff e tratar como ele quiser.

Comment: Sim, é o que eu acho (veja o último bloco de código da pergunta);

Comment: Ah! Agora acho que entendi. Mas uma coisa não faz sentido. Se o resultado vai ser apenas a diferença dos valores então os preços teriam que ser zero correto?! Pois o resultado parece ser a variação dos valores

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: sou o autor do jsondiffpatch, e meu portugues nao e o melhor :) )

Acho que vc pode obter o resultado que ta esperando com um "filtro" para gerar diferenças entre números desse jeito. o codigo:

```
var diffpatcher = jsondiffpatch.create({
  objectHash: function(obj) {
    return obj.id; // esse e o jeito de identificar objectos no seu array mesmo tendo mudado de posiçao
  }
});

var numericDiffFilter = function(context) {
  if (typeof context.left === 'number' && typeof context.right === 'number' && context.left !== context.right) {
    // dois numeros, deixar so a diferença (em lugar do array com os dois valores)
    context.setResult(context.right - context.left).exit();
  }
};
// a filterName is useful if I want to allow other filters to be inserted before/after this one
numericDiffFilter.filterName = 'numeric';

// inserir o novo filtro antes do "trivial" o primeiro quando se comparam dois valores
diffpatcher.processor.pipes.diff.before('trivial', numericDiffFilter);

// os valores que vc botou (eu corregi o id do Bacon que parece foi um typo):
var l = [
  {"id":1004,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Alface","preco":1,"quantidade":1},
  {"id":1000,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Bacon","preco":2,"quantidade":1},
  {"id":1001,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Queijo Cheedar","preco":2,"quantidade":3}
];
var r = [
  {"id":1004,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Alface","preco":1,"quantidade":2},
  {"id":1001,"idproduto":3,"forma":"Queijo Cheedar","preco":2,"quantidade":1},
  {"id":1000,"idproduto":2,"forma":"Bacon","preco":2,"quantidade":1}
];

var delta = diffpatcher.diff(l, r);
```

o resultado em `delta` e:

```
{
  "0": {
    "quantidade": 1
  },
  "1": {
    "quantidade": -2
  },
  // o idproduto do Bacon diminiu (typo?)
  "2": {
    "idproduto": -1
  },
  "_t": "a",
  // o Queijo moveu da posicao 2 a posicao 1
  "_2": [
    "",
    1,
    3
  ]
}
```

Logicamente agora esse delta ja nao pode ser usado com `.patch()` mas acho que isso e esperado neste caso (mas isso pode se resolver escrevendo un filtro de patch).

Documentação sobre estes filtros (plugins): https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch/blob/master/docs/plugins.md